# FireFox pseudo class :has() bug

Tags: css, firefox

I set "layout.css.has-selector.enabled" to true in config and still not working as it should in FireFox.

```css
:where(.wrapper){
  background-color: green;
}

:where(.wrapper:has(:first-child[onpointerdown*="append"])){
  background-color: purple;
}

.wrapper:has([data-_="1"]){
  background-color: blue;
}

[data-_="1"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div onpointerdown="this.parentElement.append(this.parentElement.firstElementChild)">Move</div>
  <div>Some text...</div>
  <div onpointerdown="this.dataset['_']=+!+this.dataset['_']">Change color</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's _experimental_. What do you expect?

Comment: It is working fine for me (latest FF on Windows10) once I set layout.css.has-selector.enabled to true. What OS are you on?

Comment: @AHaworth - When the "Change color" div is clicked, when that div's background is red,  the wrapper element background should be blue, and isn't. This is the performance-tricky bit of `:has()` - recomputing the cascade of all `:has()` dependent elements of a mutating DOM document element - so it's really not surprising that FF hasn't completed the implementation of that yet.

Comment: Same goes for the "Move" div outcome.

Comment: It's buggy for me too. It starts off looking fine with `td:has(input[type="radio"]:checked){}` but then when I tick a different radio button, which should effectively result in: `td:has(input[type="radio"]){}` the `td` is still styled as if it is `:checked`... just posting this info for troubleshooting purposes in case any Mozilla devs come across this.

Comment: See Demo here and you will understand how Firefox is partially supporting `:has` with its experimental flag enabled. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160163/6764107

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a bug in Firefox. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039 comment 47 (and the previous two) for details:

> What you're seeing is an interaction with the style sharing cache where we try to detect when we can just share the style of the elements. It's not accounting for :has, so it wrongly shares the style of the first label with the second.

If the first element in the DOM matches the `:has()` rule it will work - but as others have mentioned... there is a reason why this is behind a flag.